# DataMapper Nested conditions: count issue

Tags: ruby, nested, associations, datamapper

Here is the models:

```
class Foo
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  has n, :foo_bars
  has n, :bars, :through => :foo_bars
end

class Bar
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  has n, :foo_bars
  has n, :foos, :through => :foo_bars
end

class FooBar
  include DataMapper::Resource

  belongs_to :foo, :key => true
  belongs_to :bar, :key => true
end
```

Inserting some data:

```
f = Foo.create
b1 = Bar.create
b2 = Bar.create
b3 = Bar.create
f.bars = [b1, b2, b3]
f.save
```

So, now I have one `foo`, three `bar`s, and the `foo` has all the `bar`s. Everything is fine.

Now I want to request some `foo`s having `bar`#1 and `bar`#3:

```
Foo.all(Foo.bars.id => [1,3])
=> [#<Foo @id=1>] #ok
Foo.all(Foo.bars.id => [1,3]).count
=> 2 #why?
```

And here is the question: why array length is 1 and collection count is 2? How can I get both 1? I'd like to stick to the request with the nested conditions. Is it a bug or a misuse?

DM 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you've hit a bug. I just reported an issue with your example attached: https://github.com/datamapper/dm-aggregates/issues/3

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to get correct result by doing this for now:

```
Foo.count(Foo.bars.id => [1,3])
```